# Turn a two-dimensional function with cylindrical symmetry into a three-dimensional function

Tags: differential-equations, rotation

Say I have a function that I solved from a differential equation in 2-dimensions because I know in advance that there is cylindrical symmetry in the solution. For instance, say we obtain the solution:

```
f[x_,z_]=x^2+z^2
```

How would one go about turning this "slice" of a three-dimensional cylindrically symmetric function into its full three-dimensional form?

The function above should describe this three dimensional function along any plane that goes through the x axis. I feel like there should be an easy solution but I'm just not seeing it.

Comment: `f[x_, y_, z_] := f[x_, z_]`? Or `g[x_, y_, z_] := f[x_, z_]`, if you want less confusion. Is that what you mean?

Comment: thanks for the response! but i dont think thats what i mean. the full 3D function should reduce down to the 2D function listed above along every plane that crosses the x axis.

Comment: I don't know what you mean by a 3D function or a 2D function, I guess. Give an example of a function that reduces "down to the 2D function listed above along every plane that crosses the x axis."  I think mine does it, but you say it doesn't. Thus I must be misunderstanding something.

Comment: Some test cases would help. As you've written this, I see @MichaelE2's suggestion as matching your requirement exactly.

Comment: maybe a lower dimensional case would help? for example, if i know that a 2D solution to a PDE has cylindrical symmetry, i would exploit that by solving the PDE in 1 dimension along a line going through the origin. for instance, say the 1D solution i get is ```f[x_]=Abs[x]```. Then when I project it back into its original 2D form, it would become a cone, ```f[x_,y_]=Sqrt[x^2+y^2]``` because if you plot the cone along a line going through the origin you will get back ```f[x_]=Abs[x]```. i dont know if this helps. im really bad at explaining things, so please let me know if that made sense!

Comment: $\sqrt{x^2+y^2}$ becomes $|x|$ for only one line passing through the $x$ axis namely, $y=0$. So is it the same for "along every plane that crosses the x axis": really there is only one plane, namely $y=0$? And by "cylindrical symmetry" of this example, you do not mean radial symmetry in the $xy$ domain; you mean the cylindrical symmetry in $xyz$ space of the graph of $z=\sqrt{x^2+y^2}$, yes? And by cylindrical symmetry of the 3D function, do you mean cylindrical symmetry in the $xyz$ domain or in the 4D graph of $w=F(x,y,z)$? And for what axis of symmetry? Sorry for being confused.

Comment: sorry, i shouldve clarified that the example above was a lower dimensional version of what i was asking in the original question. instead of planes, my example with $\sqrt{x^2+y^2}$ is with lines. sorry for the confusion.

Comment: heres a clearer formulation of the math side of the problem: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4500131/turn-a-two-dimensional-function-with-cylindrical-symmetry-into-a-three-dimension. i asked on here as well because im not sure how i would implement such symmetry in mathematica specifically.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*I assume OP uses the ["standard" convention](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cylindrical_coordinate_system) where the cylindrical axis is the $z$-axis. Cylindrical symmetry means that the function does [not depend on the azimuth $\varphi$](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cylindrical_coordinate_system).*

If `f[x_,z_]` is the restriction of some function `f[x_,y_,z_]` to the $x \geq 0$ part of the $xz$-plane, and if `f[x_,y_,z_]` is cylindrically symmetric, then it is given by

```
f[x_,y_,z_]:=f[Sqrt[x^2+y^2],z];
```

Note that I am using the same symbol `f` to denote two different things, which in Mathematica is no problem because it can distinguish things with 2 arguments and things with 3 arguments.

**Example.**
Suppose the restriction to the $x \geq 0$ part of the $xz$-plane is known ("slice"):

```
f[x_,z_] := x^2+z^2;
```

Then the original, cylindrically symmetric function is

```
f[x,y,z]
(* x^2+y^2+z^2 *)
```